# error when trying to separate a integer from a decimal

Tags: python, int

I'm trying to create a module that will separate the decimal from a number as I need it for a project.
However when I test it the integer comes out fine but the decimal always gets an error:

```
def seperate(decimal):
    integer = int(decimal)
    dec = decimal-integer
    print(dec, integer)
```

if I say try to enter 2015.677 it give this: 0.6769999999999072 2015

what is wrong?

Comment: What's the error? And please show a [mcve].

Comment: Please share the error message. When I ran it in Python 3 it doesn’t product an error and returns result as expected.

Comment: ```
seperate(4.5)
0.5 4
```
I get it fine. what is the error

Comment: Is `decimal` a `str` or a `float`?

Comment: float and its not an actual error its just an innacurate calculation and I don't get why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Please check the image]Actually what i suggest is that you can try this alternative approach,
And for this to work properly we always need to pass a floating value to it, and it also works for your conditions

```
def seperate(decimal):
    integer = int(decimal)
    decimal = str(decimal)
    dec = decimal[decimal.index('.')+1:]
    return(int(dec), integer)
```

Answer (score -2):

what's the error you are getting?

I tried your code, and it worked just fine on Python 3.7

```
decimal = 3.5
integer = int(decimal)
dec = decimal-integer
print(dec, integer)
```

If you give us the error, perhaps I can help you a little bit more.

Regards!

Edit:

After reading the update on the rounding problem, i used the "round" function and returned the 0.677 part of your decimal just fine.